# Clarification of what "State" is

Tags: state, theory, lstm

Can someone give an example of what is meant by "apart from the effect of any external factors"? regarding this definition of "State" below?

"In general, the **state** of a dynamical system is a set of values that summarizes all the
information about the past behaviour of the system that is necessary to provide a unique
description of its future behaviour, apart from the effect of any external factors. "

What does this mean, "apart from the effect of any external factors"? Any examples?

(not really important, but I'm taking this from http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/INC/l12.pdf . I'm not in school. I don't have a teacher to ask.)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example, think of it this way:

`Ball` is an object sitting on the `Table` object. By default, `Ball` rolls forward and `Table` is flat.

Now, we apply the state `is-stopped` to `Ball`. -- The ball is no longer rolling forward.

However, if we then apply the state `is-tilted` to `Table`, `Ball` will then begin moving due to the tilt and gravity.

The state of `Ball` is stopped, however, external forces would cause the ball to not actually be "stopped." *This* is why the definition includes the ignorance of "the effect of any external factors."